# Travis CI - How to push into master branch?

Tags: github, travis-ci

I have a Travis CI project connected to GitHub that tries to update content in the Github repo and push them back to GitHub, both master and gh-pages branches.

However, although my travis-ci log files says everything is ok, I only see the gh-pages branch updated, but not the master branch.

My travis.yml file is:

```
language: node_js
node_js: stable

language: python
python: 3.6

# Travis-CI Caching
cache:
  directories:
    - node_modules
    - pip

# S: Build Lifecycle
install:
  - npm install
  - npm install -g gulp
  - python -m pip install requests
  - python -m pip install bs4
  - python -m pip install lxml

before_script:
  - cd archive_builder
  - python build_archive.py
  - cd ..

script:
  - gulp dist

after_script:
  - cd dist
  - git init
  - git config user.name "my git name"
  - git config user.email "my git email"
  - git add -A
  - git commit -m "travis -- update gh-page"
  - git push --force --quiet "https://${GH_TOKEN}@${GH_REF}" master:gh-pages
  - sh ../purgeCF.sh $CF_ZONE $CF_KEY $CF_EMAIL

  - cd ..
  - git add -A
  - git commit -m "travis -- update master files"
  - git push --quiet "https://${GH_TOKEN}@${GH_REF}" HEAD:master

# E: Build LifeCycle

branches:
  only:
    - master
env:
 global:
   - GH_REF: github.com/mygitname/myprojectname.git
```

In this script, I first update and build website sourcefiles with gulp, storing them into "dist" folder. Then I push content in "dist" to my gh-pages branch, and push everything else to my master branch.

The credentials are stored as security keys with Travis and should work correctly.

To push "dist/", I created a new ".git/" under "dist/" and force push it as new.

To push everything else, I could not do it because the root repository already contains ".git" folder and I do not want to lose my previous commits. It should work.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

I found most articles or answers were talking about **how to deploy to gh-pages branch**, and most ways is not work for me , i debug this issue on travis for several days, i will list key steps about **how to push to master brach on travis**

> e.g. Below is my doc repository script, travis will update readme.md automated.

1. Generate github token, you can refer to the article https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line/
2. Set Environment Variables

   `GH_REF      githu.com/clownvary/docs.git` your repository address

   `GITHUB_API_KEY      ***********` your token generated on step 1
3. Script

   ```
   os: osx
   language: node_js
   cache:
     directories:
       - node_modules
   node_js:
     - 'lts/*'
   before_install:
     - git pull
     - brew install tree
   install:
     - npm install
   script:
     - npm run updateReadme
   after_success:
     - git config user.email "travis@travis.org"
     - git config user.name "travis" # this email and name can be set anything you like
     - git add README.md
     - git commit --allow-empty -m "updated README.md"
     - git push https://clownvary:${GITHUB_API_KEY}@${GH_REF} HEAD:master  #clownvary is my username on github, you need to use yourself , do not use travis or others.
   ```

Hope this can help you

Answer (score 2):

Even though **@gary wang** method is working, there is much simpler method that can push into GitHub master branch directly.

Just add **target_branch** variable under deploy section, and assign it with **master**.

Documentation on Travis CI GitHub Pages Deployment: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/pages/

Sample contents of **.travis.yml**:

```
language: node_js
...
...
...
deploy:
  provider: pages
  skip_cleanup: true
  keep_history: true
  github_token: $github_token  # Your GitHub token set in Travis CI console
  target_branch: master        # Add this line - To push into GitHub master branch
  on:
    branch: staging            # Your GitHub repo default branch
```

This method is tested and working as per expected.